# Unknown encoder 'libx265' on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running the following command on my Ubuntu 20.04
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -f mp4 output.mp4`

I get the statement: `Unknown encoder 'libx265'`

I installed the encoder with the command `sudo apt-get install libx265-dev libnuma-dev` but I still get the same message. Do you know what I am doing wrong or how to get ffmpeg to work with this encoder?

Comment: You need a ffmpeg build with libx265 linked. Get a git master build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Hi Gyan, I'm getting the same error on a different system. The solution I posted below does not work and I uninstalled all ffmpeg builds on my system and got a git master build from the website you linked. However, I get the same error. Can you please help me?

Comment: I figured it out, there was yet another ffmpeg build in my virtual environment as well. Thank you, it works now. Maybe you can add your solution below and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get -y install \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git-core \
  libass-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libgnutls28-dev \
  libsdl2-dev \
  libtool \
  libva-dev \
  libvdpau-dev \
  libvorbis-dev \
  libxcb1-dev \
  libxcb-shm0-dev \
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
  meson \
  ninja-build \
  pkg-config \
  texinfo \
  wget \
  yasm \
  zlib1g-dev
```

as posted on the website - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

I understand I was missing an update/some package installations must have changed my previous configuration.

**Edit:** I ended up getting the same error on a different system. I turned out to have multiple installations of ffmpeg in different locations and the one I was using did not have the required builds. I solved this by removing all installations of ffmpeg (using `whereis`) and then used the build linked by Gyan in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on **Ubuntu 22.04**. For me, a `ffmpeg` installation within my conda environment was creating the problem.
I was running `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4` from a conda environment that also had `ffmpeg` installation which I came to know by running `whereis ffmpeg`. As a reference, I am pasting below the `whereis` command output

```
ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/share/ffmpeg /home/chuchu/anaconda3/envs/py382/bin/ffmpeg /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz
```

As you can see along with system-wide installations of `ffmpeg`, I also have  a conda installation. Then I tried running `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4` command after changing to another conda environment which does not contain conda installation of `ffmpeg` and it worked perfectly!